# STM32 standard method for remote firmware update

Tags: stm32, arm, bootloader

My question is about a special case for Bootloader sequence for The Discovery kit for STM32F0 series with STM32F072RBT6 MCU that we currently have implemented in some of our products in the field.

I will use ST's own bootloader to update my firmware but I want to do this remotely which means there is no way of physically shorting the BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins as described in the user manuals to go in "BOOT" mode.

—> lets say the firmware I uploaded is not a good version, it’s buggy or I want to upload a newer version of my firmware later. My Issue here is that I have no way of going back to the ST’s ROM Bootloader to get new firmware AFTER I am running the User application. If I reset the board it will start executing instructions from the flash again and not the ROM. And I can't rely on the firmware to put me back in boot mode.

Is the only solution a custom bootloader?

If the solution is a custom bootloader, I have already implemented a dummy bootloader that I download to the sections 0 and 1 (and more if needed) of my flash. This Dummy bootloader will run first all the time on reset. All it does is that I will decide to jump to the User application code in sections 2-7 of the FLASH or to the ST’s original bootloader in system memory (ROM). It will do so by setting the Main Stack pointer(MSP) to the starting address of sections mentioned,  see code below.

```
void jumpToBootloader()
{
  resetAll();

  // Remap system memory to 0x00000000
  SYSCFG_MemoryRemapConfig(SYSCFG_MemoryRemap_SystemFlash);

  __set_MSP(*((uint32_t*) 0x00000000));
  ((void (*)(void)) *((uint32_t*) 0x00000004))();
}

void jumpToMainApp()
{
  resetAll();

  // Tell processor the address of the new vector table before jumping to the main app
  NVIC_SetVectorTable(NVIC_VectTab_FLASH, MAIN_APP_OFFSET);
  __set_MSP(*((uint32_t*) (0x8000000 + MAIN_APP_OFFSET)));
  ((void (*)(void)) *((uint32_t*) (0x8000004 + MAIN_APP_OFFSET)))();
}
```

This is good as if my firmware is corrupted I can just reset and I am good to upload new code if needed.

How is this done in the industry is there a standard 3rd party tool/lib I can use that provides the same functionality as my bootloader but it is much more stable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891432/jump-to-bootloader-in-stm32-through-application-i-e-using-boot-0-and-boot-1-pins

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no definitive answer.  Questions to which the response would be a list do not fit the stack exchange mission.

Comment: field upgradability is designed into the product long before production starts.  requirements are set as to who and how upgrades can happen and that is designed in. it may be a hardware solution,software solution or a combination of both.  you have to assume that st's bootloader is tested and bullet proof, if you make your own that you rely on to re-load the rest of the firmware it has to also be bulletproof. These are COTS parts so you cant really get around corruption or destruction of the product, it becomes disposable at that point.  single point failures can happen that defeat your design

Comment: as pointed out there is a list of different solutions used in practice, so this cant really be answered.  at the end of the day for a chosen mcu, there are only so many ways you can (re)program the flash, and those are documented by the chip vendor.  whatever solution if any is used (sometimes the answer is write better code with no bugs and if the product is bad you toss it not reprogram it) has to fit within those options.